# How to pass in class to a method and call static methods on that class

Tags: java, java-8

I'm trying to write a factory class that takes in a class inherited from a specific abstract base class and calls a static method on that class to perform some logic and data manipulation before creating one or more instances of that class based on that manipulated data. So far, this is what I have:

```
public abstract class Foobar {
    public static void sayHi() {}
}

public class Foo extends Foobar {
    public static void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("Hi from Foo!");
    }
}

public class Bar extends Foobar {
    public static void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("Hi from Bar!");
    }
}

public class PolymorphicFoobar {
    public PolymorphicFoobar(Class<Foobar> cls) {
        // Do some logic before creating an instance
        cls.sayHi();
    }
}

class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        // Neither works
        new PolymorphicFoobar(Foo.class);
        new PolymorphicFoobar((Class<Foobar>)Bar.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using static methods as if they were instance methods on a `Class`. There is a much more Java (and OO) way - make them instance methods: remove the `static` modifier and in the `PolymorphicFoobar` constructor and take a `Foobar` instance as an argument.

Comment: This pretty much seems like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: It does fall into the XY Problem, you're right. I've edited the quest to make it more clear what I'm trying to achieve. Essentially, I'm trying to build a factory that takes in a class inherited from `Foobar`, calls a static method on the received class to modify and sort some data, then create one or more instances of the class based on how the modified data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** do it with *reflection* and a capture-of wildcard; like

```
public PolymorphicFoobar(Class<? extends Foobar> cls) {
    try {
        Method sayHi = cls.getMethod("sayHi");
        sayHi.invoke(cls);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And then to invoke it, the syntax is very similar to what you had (you're missing `new`, but otherwise the first form is good). Like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new PolymorphicFoobar(Foo.class);
    new PolymorphicFoobar(Bar.class);
}
```

Outputs

```
Hi from Foo!
Hi from Bar!
```